# TensorFlow word embeddings on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have the problem to understand where tensorflow executes the variables. In my case, i have a large word embedding matrix which is used by a RNN to generate text. During the text generation process, there is a lookup of the embeddings and i know that this lookup needs to be executed on CPU because GPU doesn't support it.

I want to expand my system so that there are calculations with the large embedding matrix, but this operation is very slow. I think this will also be executed on cpu, although a calculation on GPU is possible. When i loop into the tool GPU-Z during the calculation, i can see that the most time the bus interface load is very high (>60%) and the GPU load is very low (<10%).

It is very difficult to post a minimal example, i hope the problem is clear. I don't know how to debug this. Are the embedding automatically placed on the cpu because of the lookup operation? Do you have any idea how to overcome this problem?